# Ubuntu 12.04 not booting to a display manager or login manager

Tags: boot, login, display, login-screen, display-manager

When I boot up my computer with Ubuntu install on it, it's keeps booting and booting forever. It loads the boot screen but it doesn't boot up.

The only way to log in is to press Ctrl+Alt+F2, then enter my user info to login, then I enter `sudo lightdm`, then login again but only this time I load into the GUI. But when the GUI freezes, I can't do anything so I most hold down my power button on my comter to turn it off.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the graphics card in your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem like this that existed in Ubuntu 11.10. If you previously upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS you could have a couple of faulty leftover packages from 11.10.

Installing proprietary drivers could also cause LightDM to not fully boot inside the login screen. Have you tried installing the open source nVidia or ATI drivers to check for verification?

By the way you could try a few of [these suggestions for LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM/).