# Cannot start Ubuntu: shows endlessly Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, login

I can't start my computer anymore (nothing changed). It shows the Ubuntu logo with the five white dots becoming orange and white again, endlessly. No error, no login screen.

[image]

Comment: Consider trying here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163767/ubuntu-12-04-not-booting-to-a-display-manager-or-login-manager?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it and take option 3.

Comment: hit `s` during boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, I got "Read DMA"-errors, now trying to fix this problem.

Comment: You can boot from Ubuntu Live cd/dvd/usb, start Disks Utility, try to see the SMART data and test your SDA disk. 

You may have to check you SSD manufacturers web site for specific SMART software though.