# Switch user on live session gives "no passwd entry"

Tags: 14.04, users, live-environment

I cannot access my Ubuntu-system anymore (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582755/cannot-start-ubuntu-shows-endlessly-ubuntu-logo)). Now I'm booting my computer with a bootable-Ubuntu-usb-stick, this works and I try to access my files to keep my files on the hard drive safe. But when I try to copy the files to an external drive I get the error message

`The folder xxx cannot be handled because you do not have permissions the read it`

So I tried it command line by first trying switching user (the owner of the files), but this gives:

```
No passwd entry for user 'waanders'
```

I cannot access my own files, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UID of the files' owner might be different from 1000, which is the uid of the first user created. You can use the `stat` command to determine it. You can:

- use `sudo -i` to become root (no password needed on live session) and access all the files. The simplest option.
- `chown` the files to UID 1000 - might be time consuming depending on the number of files.
- add a user with UID same as that of the files (say `1001`):

  ```
  sudo adduser --uid 1001 foo
  ```

  Then switch to that user.

Comment: `sudo -i` did the trick. Thanks a lot!